# ANACONDA - Unable to install 64-bit version - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, anaconda

I am trying to install Anaconda 64-bit version on my computer with Windows 10 64 bit.
However, after the installation Anaconda doesn’t work. It doesn’t appear in the Start Menu options and if I try to run it in the folder where it was installed (`C:\Users\myuser\Anaconda3\_conda.exe`), nothing happens.

I then installed Anaconda 32-bit version and it worked, however I would like to work with the 64-bit version.

During installation, I checked the option "Register Anaconda as my default Python 3.7".

The installation of 64-bit version was much faster than the 32-bit and it seems that it doesn’t follow all the same steps.

Details of the installation of 32-bit version:

1. Extract
2. Unpacking
3. Setting up the base environment
4. Completed

Unpacking - 32-bit:

[image: Unpacking - 32-bit]]

Setting up base environment - 32-bit:

[image: Setting up base environment - 32-bit]]

Details of the installation of 64-bit version:

1. Extract (Setting up the package cache...)
2. Completed

Setting up the package cache:

[image: Setting up the package cache]]

Anaconda 64-bit -completed:

[image: Anaconda 64-bit -completed]]

I have already installed and uninstalled Anaconda several times, uninstalled all other programs that run with Python on my computer, uninstalled the antivirus Avast, but it didn’t work... Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Disabling antivirus might not be enought. In some countries (e.g., Brazil) some people have some security software (Warsaw: used in internet / home banking) that must be removed as it interferes with Anaconda 64-bits.

After setting up anaconda, Warsaw can be installed again.

Comment: Thanks, woliveirajr. I ended up setting my computer to factory configuration , reinstalled Anaconda 64-bits and it worked. However, at the moment I am using Linux instead of Windows while using Jupyter Notebook and it's way much better!

Comment: @woliveriajr you saved my life!! after 100's trys

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter in a Command Prompt the following, adjusting it as required :

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate
```

Check afterward that Anaconda was added to the PATH environment variable.
If not, add it manually.

Comment: Thanks, harrymc. I ended up setting my computer to factory configuration , reinstalled Anaconda 64-bits and it worked. However, at the moment I am using Linux instead of Windows while using Jupyter Notebook and it's way much better!